# Find groups of IDs in R

Tags: r

I have a data set that contains two 'ID' columns: one column `id` for the current ID, and another `prev_id` that that connects the observation (row) to another observation's `id`.

**Example Data**

```
d <- data.frame(
  id = c(35, 4, 3, 9, 5, 17, 11, 10, 8),
  prev_id = c(10, 3, NA, 5, NA, NA, 8, 4, NA)
)

  id prev_id
1 35      10
2  4       3
3  3      NA
4  9       5
5  5      NA
6 17      NA
7 11       8
8 10       4
9  8      NA
```

In the example above, the first observation (35, 10) indicates that it is connected to row 8 (10, 4), which is connected to row 2 (4, 3), which is finally connected to row 3 (3, NA). The NA for `prev_id` in row 3 indicates that row is not connected to another observation.

**Question**

How can I create another field, `id_group` that gives a unique identifier for each collection of observations?

**Desired Outcome**

```
  id prev_id id_group
1 35      10        1
2  4       3        1
3  3      NA        1
4  9       5        2
5  5      NA        2
6 17      NA        3
7 11       8        4
8 10       4        1
9  8      NA        4
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes a solution exists.

We don't know where the start of each chain is. However, we know the end of each chain is when `prev_id` is `NA`.

```
library('tidyverse')

d <- data.frame(
  id = c(35, 4, 3, 9, 5, 17, 11, 10, 8),
  prev_id = c(10, 3, NA, 5, NA, NA, 8, 4, NA)
)
```

First, set the `id_group`s for the chain-ends.

```
group_df <- d %>%
  filter(is.na(prev_id)) %>%
  mutate(id_group = row_number()) %>%
  right_join(d)
group_df
#>   id prev_id id_group
#> 1 35      10       NA
#> 2  4       3       NA
#> 3  3      NA        1
#> 4  9       5       NA
#> 5  5      NA        2
#> 6 17      NA        3
#> 7 11       8       NA
#> 8 10       4       NA
#> 9  8      NA        4
```

Then, iteratively update the `id_group` based on the `id_group` of the `prev_id`. Keep going until there are no more missing `id_group`s.

```
while (any(is.na(group_df$id_group))) {
  group_df <<- group_df %>%
    mutate(
      id_group = ifelse(
        is.na(id_group),
        group_df$id_group[match(prev_id, group_df$id)],
        id_group))
}

group_df
#>   id prev_id id_group
#> 1 35      10        1
#> 2  4       3        1
#> 3  3      NA        1
#> 4  9       5        2
#> 5  5      NA        2
#> 6 17      NA        3
#> 7 11       8        4
#> 8 10       4        1
#> 9  8      NA        4
```

Comment: Why are you using the super assignment operator `<<-`?